# how to connect ionic factory to webapi?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

i've been experimenting with ionic (building in online phonegap builder) and currently following this : http://mcgivery.com/ionic-using-factories-and-web-services-for-dynamic-data/

unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. i'm trying to get a user's username and compare it if it matches once i tap a button. but my app doesnt respond to taps. if there is another way to connect to webapi please do suggest. thank you.

here's my services.js code:

```
.factory('userService', ['$http', function($http) {
var users = [];

return {
    getUsers: function(){
        return $http.get("http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/users").then
        (function(response){
            users = response;
            return users;
        });
    },
    getUser: function(id){
        for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
            if(users[i].Username == id){
                return users[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}])
```

and here is my controllers.js code:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
 '$location','userFactory', 
 function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, userFactory) {
  $scope.userdata = {};
  $scope.enterlogin = function(usern) {
    if(userFactory.getUser(usern) != null)
    {
        $location.path('/page14');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Failed');
    }
}

}])
```

Comment: what is not working? do you see api returns data?

Comment: if it's working it should go to the next page if verified ok. if not, an alert box pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
 getUsers: function(){
        return $http.get("http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/users").then
        (function(response){
            users = response.data;
            return users;
        });
    },
```

Comment: thanks, but it's still not responding. is there a way to check logs while running the apk in the device?

Comment: you can debug and check or put console.log after the line users = response.data; console.log(users);

Comment: in the chrome developer console

Comment: hi, i tried it but the logs cant be seen (i ran it using ionic serve --browser chrome)

Comment: Your API is not returning the data

Comment: is there a way to test if api is returning data?

Comment: [
  {
    "Username": "Omar",
    "Password": "omar2000!",
    "Email": "omar.danga@gmail.com",
    "Balance": 100
  },
  {
    "Username": "Ganny",
    "Password": "ganny2001!",
    "Email": "ganny.rabulas@gmail.com",
    "Balance": 200
  }
]

Comment: does it return in the controller?

Comment: controller? in the ionic app?

Comment: getUsers returns a json object, getUser(id) returns a null